# Full Animation of Vessel Route

Tags: route, animation

I am trying  to  visualize the full route of a vessel from start point to an  end point including  stops (vessel stops for some time within a port area). I have three separate shapefiles:
1. Route of Vessel including coordinates and timestamp for every point (lat,long, timestamp)
2. Check-In/ Check-Out  in a port (lat, long, type:Check-In/Out)
3. Port  basins

My  goal is to  full visualize the route of a vessel into an animation including  the stops. When the vessel enters a port area I would like to  have a label pump up or point  to change color which  will indicate a check-In/ out  accordingly.

I am quite new in GIS and now I am palying  around with time slicers and mapbox, trying to  figure out  how to  do this and which  is the best  way. Can s/one please guide me what is the best way and also  easiest  way?

Comment: The QGIS plugin "Time Manager" is very effective for such animation. Anita Graser, who was one of the plugin's developers, has a number of internet "how-to" posts. I would google for that.

Comment: Thanks @StuSmith! I already  tried that, you  are right  it  is good! However, I think its possibe to include the "Check-In/ Out  Vizuaization".